# I'm currently trying to calculate the difference between two dates in sales table excluding weekend in power BI

Tags: powerbi

Can anyone help please?
I'm currently trying to calculate the  difference between two dates in sales table excluding weekend in power BI
sample data

[image]

Comment: You need to get the datediff (in days) between the 2 dates, then subtract the number the datediff (in weeks) * 2, and then adjust for edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I created a calculated column but I think you could create a Measure as well:

```
Business_Days =

    --SUNDAY(1) // MONDAY(2) // ... // SATURDAY(7)

    VAR Case_1 = WEEKDAY([Start Date]) = 7 && WEEKDAY([End Date]) = 7
    VAR Case_2 = WEEKDAY([Start Date]) = 7 && WEEKDAY([End Date]) = 1
    VAR Case_3 = WEEKDAY([Start Date]) = 1 && WEEKDAY([End Date]) = 7
    VAR Case_4 = WEEKDAY([Start Date]) = 1 && WEEKDAY([End Date]) = 1
    VAR Case_5 = WEEKDAY([Start Date]) = 1 && WEEKDAY([End Date]) IN {2,3,4,5,6}
    VAR Case_6 = WEEKDAY([Start Date]) = 7 && WEEKDAY([Start Date]) IN {2,3,4,5,6}
    VAR Case_7 = WEEKDAY([Start Date]) IN {2,3,4,5,6} && WEEKDAY([End Date]) = 1
    VAR Case_8 = WEEKDAY([Start Date]) IN {2,3,4,5,6} && WEEKDAY([End Date]) = 7
    
    RETURN

    IF( Case_1 , DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK) + n1,
    IF( Case_2 , DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK) + n2,
    IF( Case_3 , DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK) + n3,
    IF( Case_4 , DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK) + n4,
    IF( Case_5 , DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK) + n5,
    IF( Case_6 , DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK) + n6,
    IF( Case_7 , DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK) + n7,
    IF( Case_8 , DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK) + n8,
    DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],DAY)-2*DATEDIFF([Start Date],[End Date],WEEK))))))))
```

Comments:

- n1, n2, n3 ... are integers. You have to replace them by their real value.
- There may be more special cases.

Comment: Thanks for you time and help. This is highly appreciated.  I will try it and update you please. Thanks again